# Is there a way to tell how many coins are currently generated?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, transaction-fees, emission-curve, coinbase-transaction

Is there a way to show how many coins have been generated so far taking in to account the transaction fee's paid by senders?

For example if 1000 coins were generated ( issued ), and 10 transactions have occurred with a transaction fee of 1 coin each, is there any way to know that there are 990 coins available in the current money supply?

Or more simply put, is there a way to know how many coins are currently in circulation? ( Including the percentage of coins given to miners at the time from the transaction fee's )

( Please excuse my ignorance as I am kinda new to crypto )

Comment: https://revex.co/monero/  <-- shows available supply, how do I get this information from the blockchain? Does this value include the amount that has been spent on transaction fees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While running `monerod`, type in the following command:

```
print_coinbase_tx_sum <start height> <block count>
```

This will sum all the coinbase transaction outputs for the blocks defined by the arguments, while also showing how much is from emission and how much from fees. Example output of the command `print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 1000`:

```
Sum of coinbase transactions between block heights [0, 1000) is 17583.808487522075 consisting of 17583.806159241255 in emissions, and 0.002328280820 in fees
```

Also note that the fees don't disappear but go to the miner who wins the block, so the total available supply will be the `<x> in emissions` part of the output.

Looks like the command is not really optimized. I've run it from 0 to 1244879 to find the current supply and it's been running for a few hours  (ongoing).

Comment: This looks perfect however this is what happens when I try:

'monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod --version
Creating the logger system
Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.1.0-dd580d7)

monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 5 100
Creating the logger system
Error: Unsuccessful --'

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 3):

Transaction fees does not disappear. They are earned by the miners as part of the block reward, so they stay in the available money supply.

Comment: How do I know how many coins are currently in circulation? I realize they go back to the miners, but this happens over time.

Comment: http://moneroblocks.info/ "Emission". The amount of xmr "unavailable" in transaction fees is negligeable.

Answer (score 2):

Cant add to the comment, but like he was saying, the transaction fee does not disappear. Sure it's not awarded right away by your pool, but it's awarded to someone.

If its 1000 block reward, then the total supply would go up by 1000, regardless of the fee.